# How to override get_post function in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have URL like this in my WordPress **http://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=87&action=edit&lang=de-DE** and I need to override function which select post by ID from table wp_posts. I have another table in SQL and because of $_GET['lang'] parameter I need to use data from this table, so I need to override whole function, not only the WHERE part.

When I select the right post from table, than I would like to use the default template.
Is it possible to return data from overridden function back and use them in default WordPress template?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the function you are trying to override, WordPress does support that.  You can do it via a plugin or via the functions.php file depending on the functionality you wish to achieve (which is a bit hard to determine based on your question)

Here is a list of pluggable functions:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions

And here is a tutorial on how to use them:
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-wordpress-pluggable-functions-and-their-usage--wp-30189

After your comment, I am adding this addendum:

In your case, it sounds as if you want to use add_query_vars in your functions.php file so that Wordpress is aware of that query string (GET var).  Then you can use query_vars property to get your specific var (lang) and use it (along with get_results) to to query your custom table.

Add query vars in function.php:

```
function add_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = "lang";
    return $vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

This is how you get the vars from the URL in your template file or whatever:

```
$lang = get_query_var( 'lang' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Then you would just use the info you retrieve in a get_results custom query to your specific table...assuming your table has the correct prefix, etc...

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Using_the_.24wpdb_Object

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I did not find this function among pluggable functions. The only functionality I need to replace is selecting data from sql table by $_GET['post'] . Like I wrote above, I need to use another parameter $_GET['lang'] BUT this parameter is in my own table, not in default wp_posts. Is now more clear what I need?

Comment: @Sylar Updated answer...hopefully that helps...still not exactly sure I understand what you are trying to get at, but I think I do, haha.

Comment: +1 for the nice attempt, but the question is *really confusing*... It talks about the backend (!).